# Json document creation with JSONObject and JSONArray in java

Tags: java, json

Need help to create a JSON document. Below is the JSON document which I want to create using Java.

```
[{ 
   "TestCases": { 
      "Object1": [ "id", "name" ], 
      "Object2": [ "value", "title" ]  
    } 
 },
 { 
   "TestCases": { 
     "Object3": [ "id", "name" ], 
     "Object4": [ "value", "title" ] 
 } 
}]
```

Comment: You could use [this free online service](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) to create the pojos from your json

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a string formatted as you have provided and want to make a JSON object from it,in which case you can use the JSON-Simple open source library,the gradle dependency is  - 
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'

the sample code is as follows:

```
String jsonStr= "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\":45, 
\"department\":\"development\"}";
JSONObject myObj =(JSONObject)new JSONObject(jsonStr);
System.out.println(myObj.name + ":" + myObj.age);
//output - John:45
```

for JSON arrays, use JSONArray class instead.Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to create that json file using JSONObject and JSONArray . I don't want to read this file.